# html + css + react: how to provide margin to card without affecting the background top margin?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using `bootstrap 5`

As soon as I use:

```
<div className = "card card-body mt-5">
```

There is a top margin, which looks great for the card. However it pushes my background image down by the same margin. I have tried to put the card in a `div` with various container types but I can't retain the behaviour of both elements i.e. the card to have the margin from top, but the background image to start right below the header.

Full html:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/5/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css">

<div className='container-flex remove-whitespace'>
            <div style={background}>
        <div className="col-md-6 m-auto">
        <div className='conatiner'>
        <div className = "card card-body mt-5">
            <h2 className="text-center">Register</h2>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" name="username" onChange={this.onChange} value={username} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" className="form-control" name="email" 
                    onChange={this.onChange} value={email} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password" 
                    onChange={this.onChange} value={password} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password2" 
                    onChange={this.onChange} value={password2} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                        Register
                    </button>
                </div>
                <p>
                    Already have an account? <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
                </p>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

How would I go about ensuring that the background image has 0 margin from top/header while the card maintain the margin from top/header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy and quick solution is to set the padding instead than the margin

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/5/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css">

<div className='container-flex '>
            <div style="background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/id/11/600/800')">
        
        <div className='container' class="pt-2">
        <div className = "card card-body">
            <h2 className="text-center">Register</h2>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" name="username" onChange={this.onChange} value={username} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" className="form-control" name="email" 
                    onChange={this.onChange} value={email} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password" 
                    onChange={this.onChange} value={password} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password2" 
                    onChange={this.onChange} value={password2} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                        Register
                    </button>
                </div>
                <p>
                    Already have an account? <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
                </p>
            </form>
            </div>
        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/5/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css">

<div className='container-flex remove-whitespace'>
            <div style={background}>
        <div className="col-md-6 m-auto">
        <div className='conatiner'>
        <div className = "card card-body mt-5">
            <h2 className="text-center">Register</h2>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" name="username" onChange={this.onChange} value={username} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" className="form-control" name="email" 
                    onChange={this.onChange} value={email} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password" 
                    onChange={this.onChange} value={password} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password2" 
                    onChange={this.onChange} value={password2} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                        Register
                    </button>
                </div>
                <p>
                    Already have an account? <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
                </p>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```